# Timeouts and error handling in webservices - Architecture approach

Tags: web-services, architecture

I am developing webservices and have a question about timeout / exception handling approaches.

I have a webservice (WS1) and a client C. The client receives some actions from the user and calls WS1 for some operation that does not require delivering a response to the user.

I can design the error handling in the application in 2 possible ways -

1. Call WS from C. If the invocation is successful, WS will return a token. If C does not get a token for any reason (could be a failure in WS or a network timeout), it will store in the DB and some job wil retry the operation at a later time.
2. Call WS from C and end the post. If there is any issue, WS will ping back to C (in a separate call). If there is no ping back, assume that the transaction went through.

In general, what are the options to ensure that the WS invocation is successful. What are the ways to retry the operation if the transaction fails in the first attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the approaches are valid ones. What you have is simply a synchronous operation and asynchronous operation. e.g. sockets has both modes available for many years; so do e.g. file read functions.

The choice boils down to this - whether or not your client program can afford to wait for the operation to finish or not. If it can, synchronous operations are simpler to program. Else do asynchronous model with callbacks.

As far as retries go - that again depends. Retry for how long? Many programs simply try 2-3 times in a loop on failure. If your retry is of the type that retry after certain times, then you have to store information about what you are trying to do somewhere. That somewhere could be program memory, or some permanent storage. Both synchronous and asynchronous modes would require information storage for retries. Asynchronous more so because when you get a call back you need to check your store to figure out what you were attempting to do. In synchronous mode that information is many a times implicitly stored in the program stack, in for of the data variables.

Then also should retries survive program crashes? If so then you need to store the information in some offline store. I once had a telecom app; that telecom app would write a call detail record to a DB. If for some reason that failed, the program would simply write that CDR into a local file, and move on. A cron job would come and clean up the records in the local file by sending them to DB. This way the call records, which provided billing information, survived even program crashes.

Some people do such things using message queues. Message queues offer guaranteed delivery. the client sends a message. The server side gets it. The server removes the message from Q only if it is successfully able to process the message. Else the message stays; the danger here is that the message might have some permanent failure and then it would get into an infinite loop.

Getting into infinite loops because of some permanent failures, like supplying wrong parameters to the WS, is a thing that you have to handle anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and describing it in terms of sync and async. In the app that I am working on, the program crash is unlikely. The environment is heavily monitored and is self-correcting. The more pressing issue is the retrial issue. The most feasible approach is to implement a queue-based mechanism for invoking the WS from the client.